# Custom wordpress results page invidual results are listed from the bottom up(opposite dynamic code). How can I change this?

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I am using

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

in my header. And the code that is dynamically produced lists the items from top to bottom but they show up bottom to top and going into my banner.

I can only control where the bottom (first) result lands on the page so moving it down to create room would be useless if the search only brought back a few results.

I have tried to set the height and use `overflow: scroll;` but for some reason the page can't handle it and it only shows a couple results regardless of the container height.

I am no PHP guru but I can generally follow along and make corrections. I got this PHP for the results page from this site.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <p class="meta"><small>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author() ?> <?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' | ', ''); ?></small></p>
    <div class="entry">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>

</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
    <div class="navigation">
        <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
        <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
    </div>
```

The site is currently here http://testsite.saltrockdesign.com/
It is a custom site for a school project but a real client also. Obviously not finished..
Any help will result in much love and happiness from me.

Comment: your search box doesn't seem to work.  if i type in the word test, i get an error...

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. I had some left over code from something I tried to fix it with earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I can't explain WHY it's happening.  It's certainly peculiar.  But I can tell you where the problem is and how to fix it.

For some reason, this is making everything appear backwards:

```
.title {
  margin-top: -350px;
}
```

Get rid of that, and you can also get rid of the margin-top setting in .page4 and .span8.  Then just pick one of those last two elements and put in a single margin-top which gets you to where you want to be.